# How can i let C# search for a specific file in a specific map and use it as bitmap

Tags: c#, file, bitmap

I have a form application and it's ready to be used but it only works on my PC because now the path is `Dylan/desktop/...` but I want it to work for everyone.

I now have:

```
background = new Bitmap(@"D:\Dylan\Desktop\project/background.jpg");
```

I want C# to search for the map project and then pick `background.jpg` and put it into the `Bitmap background`.

Here is more of the code:

```
    Bitmap background;
    background = new Bitmap("./background.jpg");

    this.Width = 1200;
    this.Height = 850;
    this.Text = "BoompjeOrders Bot Orderer";
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
    this.BackgroundImage = (Image)background;
    this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be using a relative path

When you publish your app as an .exe or other filetypes, the folder the .exe is in will be "." so, if you should just place the image you need in the same folder and in the code reference it as `.\background.jpg` or `..\foldermyappisin\background.jpg`

Comment: Okay, and how can i do this with my icon?

Comment: Hmm your way doesn't work to...
        background = new Bitmap("./background.jpg");
This isn't working..

Comment: If you add some of your code we can help you more specifically, but as I said, just move your image file into the folder where the .exe is, then when you call the image use a path like my examples.

Comment: But thats what i did... Im having a folder named BoompjeOrders, in that i'm having all the images and fonts that im usingin my program. i also copyed all the things that are in my debugger file and pasted that in there. When i run it from that folder it doesn't even startup anymore.

Comment: Do not move your .exe from where visual studio puts it just yet, instead copy your BommpjeOrders folder into it. then use ".\boompjeOrders\background.jpg" or "..\folderwhereexeis\boompjeOrders\background.jpg". note that you should be using \ NOT /. also when you write \ in VS as a string you must escape it by writing it as double \\. That means: "..\\folderwhereexeis\\boompjeOrders\\background.jpg"

Comment: Okay but what do i have to set online to download and also let it work with other people?

Comment: it should work as long as when it installs the image is on the same directory you set it to. also sometimes when using paths it is already looking relative to the .exe so you can also try leaving the path as just "background.jpg" if it is in the same folder as the .exe.

Most published apps come in a "bin" directory and all other files are on another folder, so just set everything correctly remembering that your .exe is from where you will start searching for your files. ".." on a path means one folder back.

Comment: Well, I already tried that one with just leaving background.jpg but that didn't work. okay so right now it works. So right now im having this:
background = new Bitmap("..\\Debug\\boompjeOrders\\background.jpg");
Wih folder do my friends need to let it work? My exe is in the debug and my BoompjeOrders in Debug.
Should i just give Debug to my friends?

Comment: Hmm so when i copy the Debug file to my desktop and open my .exe from there it doesn't work anymore :/

Comment: yes, Debug should work. Copy Debug and to your desktop. and verify the .exe runs. and try using "boompjeOrders\\background.jpg" instead.

Comment: if you are using external .dll files they must also be in debug or any kind of external file for that matter

Comment: I did all what you said, but when i do "boompjeOrders\\background.jpg"it also works but when i rename Debug to something else it doesn't work anymore? Why? because in the path ("boompjeOrders\\background.jpg") there is no Debug anymore ?
Oh and it dosn't load my icon anymore :(

Comment: you have some visual studio setting set up wrong, or are missing a file for the exe to run correctly. you must set your project to save all dependencies in the output folder when it compiles. Also the path should work even if you change the name of debug. the thing about relative paths is that you should not be writing things like "C:\" or any other kind of folder name that might not be the same in a user's pc. we tried the easy and quick way, but you could also try doing it like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx

Comment: I just fixed my icon. it was still on another location.
But when i change debug to something else on my desktop it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: write down the hierarchy of your folder, do the same for your VS project or use a picture. Or you can try just using the name of the folder you want to use instead of debug in your paths and see if it works, although it should work regardless of how you change debug... Does your app have an app.config file? if so also post the contents of that file

Comment: Thank you so much, it just worked. 
I dont know what I did wrong but now i can change the name etc so tysm!

Comment: @DylanGaytant: did this work for you? Than you should mark it as answer and/or upvote it.